# A problem adding react to an existing website

Tags: html, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to add the react app I made to my existing website, I followed the existing documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) but apparently the navigator doesn't regconize the import parts of my code, brobably because the babel parser isn't working properly? 
Here's my index.js code:

I tried the babel as a type in my script, but no luck
here's my index.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

here's my index.html code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-content-loader@3.4.1/dist/react-content-loader.min.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

the console output:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in index.js:1

Answer (score 2):

You are loading your dependencies as globals using dedicated `<script>` elements.

Don't use `import` as well.

---

You are using JSX. You *need* to mark the script containing it as `text/babel`.